# How to get model and serial number of monitor?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd

I need to get a model and serialnumber of monitor that connected to my PC. 
It would better if it realises in Python, but in powershell it would be okay too.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some info in link below.[solution](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/658220-get-monitor-manufacturer-model-and-serial-number)
Using wmi classes we can take info from our monitors, then for each monitor takes values from fields and write it to file.

```
$Monitors = Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi
$LogFile = "d:\monitors.txt"

"Manufacturer,Name,Serial" | Out-File $LogFile

ForEach ($Monitor in $Monitors)
{
    $Manufacturer = ($Monitor.ManufacturerName|where {$_ -ne 0}|ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""
    $Name = ($Monitor.UserFriendlyName  |where {$_ -ne 0}| ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""
    $Serial = ($Monitor.SerialNumberID  |where {$_ -ne 0}| ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""

    "$Manufacturer,$Name,$Serial" | Out-File $LogFile -append
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers